# How to get the deleted date of a CalendarEvent?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a two-way script to go back and forth between Google Sheets and Google Calendar, and I'm wondering how to tell whether a CalendarEvent has been deleted.

Currently, I store event IDs in the spreadsheet every time an event is created, then I use that event ID to read/write subsequent updates to that event:

```
var event = eventcal.getEventById(eventId);
```

But I don't see a way in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#methods) to determine whether a CalendarEvent has been deleted in the calendar.  Retrieving a recently deleted event using the method above simply returns the CalendarEvent since it lives in the Recycle Bin.  `event.getLastUpdated()` is also too general for me since I'd like to do different things for updated/rescheduled events and deleted events.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Reports API instead

When [listing the Activities](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) for a specific App you can specify the `eventName` and `filters` parameters to look for [deleted events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/calendar#delete_event) given a certain Calendar.

### References

- [Reports API > Aplication Name](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list#ApplicationName)
- [Method: activities.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list)
- [Google Calendar > Delete Event](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/calendar#delete_event)